# In Selenium, how to send text to the text area and click buttons in div element having only style

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, button, automation, textarea

How to click on the **buttons** and **textarea** in a div with no class or id, through automation using Selenium:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use below `xpath` to click on `button`:

- Button ok: `//input[@value='OK']`
- Button Cancel: `//input[@value='Cancel']`

For `textarea`, you can write `relative xpath` using above mentioned xpath:

`//input[@value='OK']/../textarea`